# Is outlook.com whole site using silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, outlook.com

I was trying to send an email using outlook.com then I just seen that chrome says `Silverlight extension crashed` Now I want to know is outlook.com using silverlight or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It is using Silverlight. You can tell from this part in the source:

```
requiredSilverlightVersion: "4.0.50401"
```

Comment: And probably because Chrome says *"Silverlight extension crashed"*

Comment: Do you know which parts are using silverlight?

Comment: @Blender: I was going to mention that too, but it could have just been an incredible coincidence, so... :)

Comment: @MahdiGhiasi: No, and I'm not going to reverse-engineer it and find out. (Although one can infer that there is at least a slideshow using it - see `Microsoft.Live.Silverlight.Slideshow.xap` in the source also.)

Comment: @Blender It can be just a small part of site! not whole site!

Comment: The parts that crash all the time.

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee: If it's a part of the site, the site is using it. That was your original question, no?

Comment: @Blender I didn't say my question correct. I edited it's title.